# Sipdroid build errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors, sipdroid

I'm trying to build sipdroid in Eclipse Juno. I've went into properties and set the project to platform 2.2/ API 8, into Java Build Path and ticked the Android 2.2 box.  But I am still getting 9 of these build errors. Has anyone had this problem?

The method onAccuracyChanged(Sensor, int) of type InCallScreen must override a superclass method

The method onSensorChanged(SensorEvent) of type InCallScreen must override a superclass method

The method onLongClick(View) of type VideoCamera must override a superclass method

The method onError(MediaPlayer, int, int) of type VideoCamera must override a superclass method

The method onClick(View) of type VideoCamera must override a superclass method

The method onClick(DialogInterface, int) of type Settings must override a superclass method

The method onDismiss(DialogInterface) of type Sipdroid must override a superclass method

The method getOption(int) of type PlainDatagramSocketImpl must override a superclass method

The method setOption(int, Object) of type PlainDatagramSocketImpl must override a superclass method

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891317/the-method-must-override-a-superclass-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably compiling with java 5, which does not allow having

```
 @Override
```

on interfaces implementations.

Comment: Solved! changed my java compiler to 1.6 and errors are all gone! Thanks Eugene